# How to create user in test class with ability to add default opportunity team member

Tags: unit-test

There are some users which have "Automatically add my default opportunity team to opportunities that I create or open opportunities that are transferred to me" check box is true .So as soon as they create opportunity opportunity team member gets created.
Is there any way where we can create an user with this capability.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, all Apex code runs in system mode, where the permissions and record sharing of the current user are not taken into account. The system method runAs enables you to write test methods that change the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s record sharing is enforced. The runAs method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing.

You can use runAs only in test methods. The original system context is started again after all runAs test methods complete.

The runAs method ignores user license limits. You can create new users with runAs even if your organization has no additional user licenses.

```
@isTest
private class TestRunAs {
     public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
       // Setup test data
      // This code runs as the system user
       Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
    User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

    System.runAs(u) {
         Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
         // put required field
         insert opp;

         OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember (OpportunityId = opp.id,UserId = u.id,TeamMemberRole = role);
 insert otm;

    }
  }
}
```